# Activate conda environment in Dockerfile and use in gitlab ci

Tags: docker, gitlab, conda

I have a dockerfile as follows:

```
FROM continuumio/miniconda:4.7.10

COPY environment.yml ./

RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

CMD ["source activate my-environment"]
```

Then, from the terminal, I run

```
docker build -t myrepo/myimage:v1 .
docker push myrepo/myimage:v1
```

I was then expecting that, if I write my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file like this:

```
image: myrepo/myimage:v1

stages:
  - Static Analysis

flake8:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
  - flake8 --max-line-length=120
```

then it would work. Note that `environment.yml` includes `flake8==3.7.8`.

However, the following error is returned:

```
/bin/bash: line 83: flake8: command not found
```

How can I modify `Dockerfile` (or `.gitlab-ci.yml`) so that this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to be answering my own question so soon, but I found the solution - might as well keep this up in case it benefits anyone.

Solution is to modify `gitlab-ci.yml` as follows:

```
image: myrepo/myimage:v1

stages:
  - Static Analysis

flake8:
  stage: Static Analysis
  script:
  - source activate my-environment
  - flake8 --max-line-length=120
```